# How to read multiple numbers in a textbox and add them in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, split

What i am trying to do is to make an WPF Application which allows the user to enter 5 numbers, separated by space, in a text box. Next they press the calculate button which gives them the average of those 5 numbers.

I did this successfully in console mode but now I am really confused on how to go about with this.

I have created the textbox and the button and a textblock where I will show the number.
I think I have managed to split the text entered. However, I can't seem to figure out what to do next.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text.Split(' ');
    }
}
}
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Should it be hard-coded only for 5 numbers? And what happens if the users exceeds the limit of 5 numbers?

Comment: 1) Get your numbers as a sting with `.Text` property of your textbox. 2) Use `String.Split()` method to get each numbers 3) Parse them to `int`. 4) Get sum of them and divide `5`. 5) If your count of numbers can change, assign your int values an array, use `Enumerable.Sum()` method to get total and divide it with `.Count` property.

Comment: you need to split your text data by space...

Comment: In your console app, create a method takes a string as parameter and return the sum as you want. Simply copy that method to your wpf app and send it the content of your textbox.

Comment: @RobertLangdon No it doesn't have to be hardcoded for 5 number. If it exceeds 5 numbers it should include the 6th number as well when calculating the average.

Comment: @liran63 how do I send it to the content of my textbox?

Comment: Don't send it to the content of your textbox; send the content of your textbox to the method as parameter.

Comment: @SonerGönül can you show me a code i can use a reference because what you say makes sense to me. But I don't know how to execute it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the array returned by Split to calculate the average of elements using the [Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399409(v=vs.110).aspx) but first you have to convert the array of string to array of numbers like `int` or `double` etc.

```
var avg = txtbox.Text.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).Average(c=>c);
```

Assuming you want to get average of double instead of int.

```
var avg = txtbox.Text.Split(' ').Select(double.Parse).Average(c=>c);
```

**Edit** Since we are returning the same value that is being passed to Average method we can use parameter less Average method.

```
var avg = txtbox.Text.Split(' ').Select(double.Parse).Average();
```

Comment: what exactly does this do: Average(c=>c)

Comment: The is lambda expression, the first c is for each element of array that is passed as parameter and second c is value being returned from the anonymous method. Although we can omit this. You can read more about the lambda here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Ah ok thanks. 

Once i use the solution you suggested. I seem to be struggling to get the avg variable to show on the wpf window. Furthermore, when i click the button nothing happens.

Comment: You need to assign the result to some GUI control in order to see result of Form. Suppose you have txtResult in your form then txtResult.Text = avg.ToString(); would show the result on form.

Comment: ah but when i use the toString method it says there is no double when in fact the parsedouble method is used

Comment: private string Text;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String[] numbers = txtbox.Text.Split(' ');
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (var num in numbers)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(num);
            }

            double avg = sum / (double)numbers.Length;
            txtResult = avg.ToString;
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: i just posted the code in the question...well the updated one.

Comment: avg.ToString should be avg.ToString();

Comment: ah. cannot implicitly convert type string to system.windows.control.textblock

Comment: Use txtResult.Text = avg.ToString();

Answer (score 2):

```
String [] numbers = textBox2.Text.Split(' ');
int sum=0;
foreach (var num in numbers)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(num);
}

double avg=sum/(double)numbers.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Split returns a `String[]`. Save the value in a variable and parse the items to ints/doubles when you sum up the value.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] items = txtbox.Text.Split(' ');

    //cast and add the values.
}
```